# Create a CubeGrid in Three.js

Tags: three.js

In Three.js there is a `GridHelper` that allows you to create a plane grid easily, just like this:

```
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions, colorCenterLine, colorGrid);
```

You can see a result example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor).

What I want to do is to create a box/cube grid, exactly like this:

[image]

I need to have a cube, because later I'll want to know, for example, if an object it's inside the cube (dynamically).

I wasn't able to find a helper that do what I need, so my idea is to take the [GridHelper source code](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/GridHelper) and use a `BoxBufferGeometry` instead of a `BufferGeometry`, but I don't even know if that's possible. I want to add that I do not have much knowledge in the field of 3D graphics, I'm just starting.

I'd love to hear you thoughts about this: I'm going in the right direction? How would you approach this problem?

Comment: You can change the order of indices of a box buffer geometry, and then use this geometry with `THREE.LineSegments()`.

Comment: @prisoner849 Wouldn't you need to completely replace the `index` `BufferAttribute` of `BoxBufferGeometry`? The box needs (if not hollow) 36 indices per cube (6 indices per side * 6 sides = 36 indices / cube), but a wire frame like this would only need 24 per cube (2 indices per edge line * 12 edges = 24 indices / cube).

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes, it will be a copy of that geometry with the replaced `index` buffer attribute.

Comment: Do you really need each segment to be a box? Could you not have one large box with a texture / shader for the lines? [HERE](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simple_lines.html) is a shader that could be adapted.

Comment: @2pha That solution doesn't work for me. I've edited the question for more clarification, sorry I wasn't accurate enough!

Comment: @fsinisi90 It is best to show what you have tried. Here is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/n23on00y/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally used the approach that @WestLangley proposed:

```
var createBoxGrid = function (base, height, translateY, divisions, color) {
    boxGrid = new THREE.Group();
    boxGrid.name = "BoxGrid";
    var box3 = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(-base / 2, 0, -base / 2), new THREE.Vector3(base / 2, height, base / 2));
    var box3Helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(box3, color);
    var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(base, divisions, color, color);
    boxGrid.add(box3Helper);
    boxGrid.add(gridHelper);
    boxGrid.translateY(translateY);
    return boxGrid;
};
```